VerneMQ handling client disconnections in a clustered environment
VerneMQ broker with 3 nodes A,B and C is deployed in Kubernetes with clustering enabled. Assume that a client x is connected to Node B. A request to disconnect client x is sent to the broker and the load balancer lands the request in Node A (where the actual client is connected to Node B), and the client disconnection is not happening. Disconnection is success only when the request is received by the Node where the client is connected (Node B in this case).
As per my understanding, when clustering is enabled, the disconnect request will be propagated to all the nodes in the cluster leading to successful disconnection of the client.
Am I missing any configuration here ? Any help would be much appreciated !
Cheers.

Please be more specific by what you mean by "disconnect request". In general, administrative disconnects based on vmq-admin session disconnect client-id=x work on any cluster node. Of course, MQTT disconnect frames can only be sent in-session by the owning client connected to a specific cluster node, but you seem to want to do an administrative disconnect command.

Thanks for replying. Ofcourse, administrative disconnect command does the job when executed from any node.

Thanks for replying @AndréF. Ofcourse, administrative disconnect command does the job when executed from any node. I use a IoT device telemetry data collection platform called astarte, where it has a custom vernemq plugin written on top of vernemq broker. The disconnection i talked about is the disconnection request triggered by one of the components of astarte called Data Updater Plant to the VMQ plugin.

Okay, I know Astarte but not well enough to advise on those requests from the plugin.
